# Parsing a HttpResponse JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, http-post, httpresponse

I am trying to do a HTTP post request to a web API and then parse the received HttpResponse and access the key value pairs in the body. My code is like this:

```
public class access {

// http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/json/product/post
public static void main(String[] args) {


    HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://XXXXXXX/RSAM_API/api/Logon");

// Request parameters and other properties.
    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserId", "XXXXX"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", "XXXXXX"));
    try {
       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));


//Execute and get the response.
       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

       BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
       String line;
       while(null !=(line=rd.readLine())){

           System.out.println(line);
       }
       System.out.println(response);

       String resp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
       JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(resp);

   }
   catch (Exception e){

       e.printStackTrace();
   }

}

}
```

I am trying to access the body by converting it to a JSONObject with these 2 lines of code:

```
String resp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
           JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(resp);
```

But I get an error in the second line saying:

```
JSONObject
(java.util.Map)
in JSONObject cannot be applied
to
(java.lang.String)
```

Not sure if this is the correct approach. Is there a way to do what I am trying to do?

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

**EDIT:**
So when I try to print the response body using the following lines,
`String resp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
System.out.println(resp);`

I get the result: `{"APIKey":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx","StatusCode":0,"StatusMessage":"Y‌​ou have been successfully logged in."}`

I am looking for a way to parse this result and then access each element. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Post what is in `String resp`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, posted it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to JsonSimple's JsonObject documentation it takes map in the constructor but not a String. So the error you are getting what it says.
You should use `JSONParser` to parse the string first.
Its also better to provide the encoding as part of `EntityUtils.toString` say UTF-8 or 16 based off your scenario.

`IOUtils.toString()` from `Apache Commons IO` would be a better choice to use too.

Comment: I tried to parse the String using JSONParser as suggested by @M.Navy in his answer. But I get an error with the parsing. 
`JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
 JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(response.getEntity().getContent().toString());` 
But I get this error:
 `Unexpected character (o) at position 0. at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:610) at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(JSONParser.java:‌​269) at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:118) at access.main(access.java:65)`

Comment: Try this ```JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())); ```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below line to parse the JSON:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(resp);
```

The above lines will vaildate the JSON and through exception if the JSON is invalid.

Comment: As I've posted in My edit, the line `String resp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());` is throwing me an error. I tried do this though:       `JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(response.getEntity().getContent().toString());`
But I get this error: `Unexpected character (o) at position 0.
 at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:610)
 at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(JSONParser.java:269)
 at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:118)
 at access.main(access.java:65)
`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to read the response in the extra `while` loop. EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); will do this for you. As you read the response stream before, the stream is already closed when comming to response.getEntity().

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, the next line `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(resp);` still gives me error saying `Error:(49, 44) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.util.Map`

Comment: So do `System.out.println(resp)` and post the output. The response is probably not a JSON or faulty.

Comment: This is what I get: `{"APIKey":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx","StatusCode":0,"StatusMessage":"You have been successfully logged in."}` I've been getting this result. I am not sure if it is json but I need to parse it and access the elements in the body. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What is the FQN of JSONObject ? What JSON lib + version do you use ?

Comment: I am using JSON simple 1.1.1. I am not sure what you meant by FQN of JSONObject..

Comment: Mhmmm ... there is no JSONObject(String) constructor in the API doc http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/index.html?help-doc.html. This won't compile. and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name

Comment: Thanks for the info. Looks like I just have to parse the String itself.